# Photoshop - Partially-transparent PNG's?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, transparency

Is it possible to do partially-transparent PNG's in Photoshop CS4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. Just create an image with partial transparency and save it as PNG.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the best way to do this would be to adjust the opacity of the layer before saving the file.

Comment: That depends on what kind of transparency you want. If you want to turn an opaque image into a half-transparent one, then yes. For nearly all other uses that doesn't suffice.